# Youtube Data API - How to get video comments from multiple video id

Tags: python, youtube-api

is there a way to get list of Youtube Comment using Youtube API from multiple video id?

This is my video id

```
video_ids = [
    'QSWYyoF79oE', 
    'Wh66ThpxvI4', 
    'weG-sqHHCB8', 
    '8dgEh5crj0I', 
    'SydRcrZ166A', 
    'Svz5F8J1Ap0', 
    'Lj_zPn3GsjE', 
    'g89VhNDBrsY', 
    ]
```

I tried using like this

```
request = youtube.commentThreads().list(part='snippet, replies', videoId= ','.join(video_ids), maxResults = 50)
response = request.execute()
```

And this is the response, still error. Is there solution or other way?

````
returned "The video identified by the <code><a href="/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#videoId">videoId</a></code> parameter could not be found.". Details: "[{'message': 'The video identified by the <code><a href="/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#videoId">videoId</a></code> parameter could not be found.', 'domain': 'youtube.commentThread', 'reason': 'videoNotFound', 'location': 'videoId', 'locationType': 'parameter'}]">```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate outside the http request:

```
for video_id in video_ids:
    request = youtube.commentThreads().list(part='snippet, replies', videoId=video_id, maxResults = 50)
    response = request.execute()
```